# re-ordering views when switching from portrait to landscape mode (iOS Xcode swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation

I have a user interface (light grey) and image parts (dark grey).

when in portrait mode I'd like to achieve the following:

[image]

If I run on an iPhone 4/5 I won't have enough space to show the image.
So when rotating to landscape mode I'd like to achieve the following:

[image]

Is it something I can achieve through auto layout?

Any pointers to documentation?

I'm new to Xcode/swift. If it's too complicate I might simply force one mode.

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve different layout for different orientation (or device) you should use Size Classes and AutoLayout.

In the bottom of your storyboard you should see *Any Any*, this means that your view controllers will be displayed in the same way on all devices and orientations. If you click on it you can select a new Size Class (the description will help choosing the right one for the desired device and orientation). Then you can change the constraints to arrange the views differently.

Now you will have your views with two sets of constraints: one is applied for the Size Class you have selected, the other will be applied to any other Size Classes.

If you never used constraints to arrange your views here's a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1) to start with.

Comment: you've given a lot of reading and testing but it looks to cover my case. the auto layout is powerful but you need your driving license.... Thanks!

Comment: fastidious and not easy but it works. I'm using v7 which automates somewhat more. Thanks.

Comment: It can be tedious at the beginning but when you get used to it you can make almost anything :)